# Calculate the variance of the random variable $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance, density-function

The graph of the density function of the random variable $X$ is an isosceles triangle with basis the intervall $[-1/2,1/2]$. Which is the variance $s^2(X)$ ?

I have done the following:

It is $s^2(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$.

We consider the funcion $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{4}(x+1/2) & \text{ for } -1/2\leq x\leq 0 \\ \frac{1}{4}(1/2-x) & \text{ for } 0\leq x\leq 1/2 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwiese }\end{cases}$$ Then we use the definition of the expected value.

Is the function $f$ correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the function $f(x)$ is for the probability density function I would change the scaling factor. Ideally you want the pdf to integrate/have an area of 1. As such you should change $\frac{1}{4}$ to 4.

You can get this from calculating the area of the triangle. $A = \frac{1}{2}bh$
Where $b$ in this case is 1 and $h$ is given by your maximum value - the value at $x=0$.

Comment: Ok! So we use the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}4(x+1/2) & \text{ for } -1/2\leq x\leq 0 \\ 4(1/2-x) & \text{ for } 0\leq x\leq 1/2 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwiese }\end{cases}$$ Is the variance then $$\int x^2f(x)-\left (\int xf(x)\right )^2$$ ? Then the result is $\frac{1}{24}$, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah the variance equation is correct and I'm also getting $\frac{1}{24}$ as my answer for the evaluation of that integral.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace $\frac 1  4$ by  $4$. As it stands, your function does not integrate to $1$.
The variance is $\int x^{2}f(x)dx-(\int xf(x)dx)^{2}$.

Comment: Ok! So we use the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}4(x+1/2) & \text{ for } -1/2\leq x\leq 0 \\ 4(1/2-x) & \text{ for } 0\leq x\leq 1/2 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwiese }\end{cases}$$ Isn't the variance $$\int x^2f(x)-\left (\int xf(x)\right )^2$$ or without $x$ the second integral?

Comment: I get the result is $\frac{1}{24}$, is that correct?

Comment: @MaryStar Sorry about the typo.

Comment: No problem! Is my result correct?